# Xamarin.Mac project crashes at startup, what am I doing wrong ?

Tags: mono, monomac, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I downloaded Xamarin Studio (4.0.1), and created a new Xamarin.Mac project via the template. Without changing any code, I try to run the app. It immediately crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (even before the debugger can attach). These are the details from the error report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000008fe01030

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):   eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x00000000  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x00000000   edi: 0x00000000  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0x00000000  esp: 0x00000000    ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x8fe01030   cs: 0x0000001b    ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000000   cr2: 0x8fe01030 Logical CPU: 2

Binary images description not available
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make the project work ? Is there anything obvious I should check ?

Comment: Which OS are you running it on?

Comment: It is on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: Check out that post.  I had to upgrade to Mountain Lion to get it working.  It does not appear to work on Lion yet.
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1534/hello_mac-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in Xamarin Studio 4.0.2

Comment: I upgraded to 4.0.2, and it still does not work. I guess I should try upgrading to Mountain Lion.

Comment: Sorry, It _does_ work in 4.0.2. Just remember to Rebuild All before trying ;)

Comment: Ah, yea, I probably should have mentioned that!